# Gstreamer: Invalid address family

Tags: networking, ffmpeg, udp, gstreamer, vlc

May I ask how do you make sense of this error from gstreamer?

[image]

I am trying to stream a rtsp server which ffmpeg and vlc are able to but gstreamer is giving me the above error.

Answer (score 0):

If the server that you are trying to connect to is `localhost` and you are connecting from a Docker or some other CI/CD container, you may want to try `127.0.0.1` instead. `localhost` can resolve to the IPV6 address `::1` and IPV6 is [not enabled by default on Docker](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/).